# PHP 5.6 can do Amazing Things! I can't use static vars of class in __construct

Tags: php, class, static

Why this code doesn't work?

```
final class Db
{
    private static $data = [];

    private function __construct()
    {
        self::$data['host']  = 'localhost';
        self::$data['user']  = 'mysql';
        self::$data['passw'] = 'mysql';
        self::$data['db']    = '123';
    }

    public static function test()
    {
        var_dump(self::$data);
    }
}
Db::test();
```

I read the official documentation in php.net but found nothing.
It's very interesting situation.

Comment: `__construct` is triggered on an object's scope when a new instance is instantiated. Did you instantiate an object anywhere?

Comment: if you never run the constructor, then your values never get assigned/defined, so... what exactly is the problem here, other than PEBKAC?

Comment: You will experience this behavior in any other (5.x) version of PHP and come to that, in any OOP language. It all boils down to mixing up static (class) and object context.

Comment: You could do all of this without trying to use classes.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by *Pepmap modder* is spot on, you are **expecting** a call to a constructor on a static object, that isn't instantiated (constructed).  You can rename the method and explicitly call it before you call the test method. I added a bit of code to allow you set it by passing an argument.

The static variable is fine.

```
final class Db
{
    private static $data = [];

    public static function initData($data = NULL) {
        if ($data) {
            self::$data = $data;
        }
        else {
            self::$data['host']  = 'localhost';
            self::$data['user']  = 'mysql';
            self::$data['passw'] = 'mysql';
            self::$data['db']    = '123';
        }
    }

    public static function test() {
        var_dump(self::$data);
    }
}
Db::initData();
Db::test();
```

Comment: Thanks, sir. I understood